# Javascript menu not displaying all pages correctly

Tags: javascript, php, debugging, menu, slideshow

I'm currently working on this site: http://wonzentest.wonzen.dk
The thing is, my menu is dynamically created through javascript, checking a folder for the pages and filling them into an array.

All though this works smoothly, there is 1 problem.

On my frontpage, there is a javascript slideshow, which also works flawlessly, until i changed my menu from pure php, to the javascript.

Now whenever you press the frontpage link in the menu, the javascript slideshow doesnt show the images, kind of acting like the dimension and layout of the slideshow dissepears when you press the link.

If you refresh, or press the logo the script works fine again.

Does anyone have an idea where the error could be?
I will upload my different code files on request, I'm not sure were you wanna look.

Javacsript menu: http://pastebin.com/uyppaDYS

This is my frontpage .php:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script class="secret-source">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype      : 'slide',
        height        : 480,
        width         : 960,
        responsive    : true,
        randomstart   : true,
        nexttext : '<div class="hovernavright"><img src="../Images/leftarrow.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" /></div>',
        prevtext : '<div class="hovernavleft"><img src="../Images/rightarrow.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" /></div>',
        usecaptions : true,
        automatic : true
      });

    });
  </script>

  <style>
  #content {
      background-color: transparent;

  }
  </style>
</head>
```

And

```
<div id="banner-slide">

   <ul class="bjqs">
    <li><img src="../Images/HQ/Wonzenmad.jpg" title="Wonzen" /></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/Wonzenmad.jpg" title="Velkommen til Wonzen!" /></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/Wonzenmad1.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad3.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/Wonzenmad2.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad4.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad5.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad6.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad7.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad8.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad9.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
      <li><img src="../Images/HQ/wonzenmad10.jpg" title="Wonzen - Krydrer din hverdag!"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>



<div id="frontpagetext">
 <h2>Alle skal have råd til kvalitet</h2>
 <hr class="toplineff" />
 <hr class="bottomlineff" />
 <p>Vi støtter alle studerende med 15% rabat på hele vores menukort ved fremvisning af studiekort</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are not sure what code to post it means you haven't properly debugged your code and isolated the problem part.

Comment: That's why I'm writing here. I've looked through the code, for my capabilities. But debugging tiny errors isn't my strong suit. 
I would properbly just we-write the menu to make the frontpage button refresh the entire page = Problem solved, but that's not good enough in this case

Comment: Well I'm sorry to say this. But debugging is one of the most important aspects of developing.

Comment: Don't be xD 
I know it is, but I've tried what I could, for me to keep staring at it wont help, I need to get "directions", and I'm not ashamed of admitting that. 
You'll learn something everyday, maybe someone could teach me this today.

Comment: Ok so I've found out that the images changes their height to 0px when frontpage menu link is clicked...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best practice. But try adding the jQuery sliding code in a separate function and call it when,

1. the document is ready
2. onclick of home
3. onclick of logo

Comment: The thing is, it works fine when i click the logo, and it's already set to document.ready. 
How would i go about telling it the only when frontpage menu is pressed then load it? 
I don't want it to load it on every menu click, and since the menu is dynamically created, I don't know how to go about doing this.